# Javascript how is the const variable being reassigned in this problem?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

The following code below will take an array as input such as

`["t","h","e"," ","s","k","y"," ","i","s"," ","b","l","u","e"]`

and return

`[ 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 's', 'k', 'y', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e']`

In the `reverseWord` function, the `const temp = s[left]` variable will be reassigned to a new value every time the function recursively calls itself. I am trying to understand how that works because I know a "const" variable cannot be reassigned. My intuition is saying that a new const temp variable is made everytime the function recursively calls itself? which makes it seem like you are reassigning a const variable but really you are creating a new variable everytime? can someone please further explain, thank you

```
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    // reverse the entire array
    s.reverse();
    // function to find the end word inside the array, this is a word that you need to reverse
   const findEndWord = (ind) => s[ind] === ' ' || ind === s.length ? ind : findEndWord(ind + 1);
    const reverseWord = (left, right) => {
        if(left >= right) return;
        const temp = s[left];
        s[left] = s[right];
        s[right] = temp;
        reverseWord(left + 1, right -1);
    }
    // the whole logic using the functions above to find the word in the array 
    // and the other function to actually reverse the word in the array
    // this logic will find the end word in the array and then reverse the word,
    // lastly it will increment the index to the right spot to find the next word.
    let index = 0;
    while(index < s.length) {
        const end = findEndWord(index);
        reverseWord(index, end - 1)
        index = end + 1;
    }
    return s;
};

console.log(reverseWords(s));
```

Comment: [`const` has block level scope.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: The keyword you need to use for better understanding of this behaviour is [`Scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Answer (score 4):

> In the reverseWord function, the const temp = s[left] variable will be reassigned to a new value every time the function recursively calls itself.

No, it won't. :-) A **different** `temp` constant, specific to that other call to the function, gets assigned the new value. The `temp` constant that exists in the original call is unchanged (as is its nature). Each call to the function gets its own set of local parameers/variables/constants. (This fact is often central to recursive functions working correctly.)

Here's a simpler example with some logging:

```js
function example(x, fns) {
    // Double the parameter's value and store it in a constant
    const temp = x * 2;
    // Push a function into `fns` that will show *this call's* `x` and `temp` values
    fns.push(() => console.log(`x = ${x}, temp = ${temp}`));
    // Potentially recurse
    if (x - 1 > 0) {
        example(x - 1, fns);
    }
}

// Call the example function, passing in an array that it
// will push functions to
const fns = [];
example(5, fns);
// Call the functions, which show us the different variables/etc. in each call
for (const fn of fns) {
    fn();
}
```

In that example, the first call to `example` theoretically¹ creates what the spec calls a *lexical environment object* which will contain all of the top-level declarations for that function call (including `temp`). When `example` calls itself, a new, separate lexical environment object is created for that second call. Etc. Normally, if a function returns and no closures were created within it, the lexical environment and its contents are discarded, but in the above I'm creating functions and storing them in `fns` so that we can see those values, which keeps those distinct lexical environments alive (since the functions close over them).

---

¹ "theoretically" because the JavaScript engine can implement it any way it wants, provided it behaves the way the spec says it behaves. And while they may use an internal object for a lexical environment, they may also be able to avoid it and just use values pushed on the stack.